# new SoapClient() not working within class

Tags: magento2, php

I am new with SoapClient(). I have a code which I execute with normal PHP script it works fine. But when I try to put that code within class structure it throws an exception as below :

```
$url = "https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl";
$soapclient = new SoapClient($url);
$params = array("digitalKey" => 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX', 
     "token" => "XXXXXX",
     "paymentAmountInCents" => "1600",
     "customerName" => "User Test",
     "paymentReference" => "1549678");
$response = $soapclient->ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment($params);
```

Class base

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ' https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl' in 

<?php
class HDEziDebit{
    public $DigitalKey = '';
    public $PublicKey = '';
    //public $PciMode = '';
    public $Environment = '';

    public $pciURL = '';
    public $nonpciURL = '';
    public $pulicRestURL = '';

    public function __construct($DigitalKey, $PublicKey, $Environment){
        // if (! in_array($PciMode, array('pci', 'nonpci','public-rest'))) {
        //  throw new Exception("Invalid PCI mode");
        // }
        if (! in_array($Environment, array('live', 'test'))) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid environment');
        }
        $this->DigitalKey = $DigitalKey;
        $this->Environment = $Environment;
        $this->PublicKey = $PublicKey;
        $this->initializeConfigurations();
    }

    public function initializeConfigurations(){
        $domain = '';
        switch ($this->Environment) {
            case 'live':
                $domain = 'https://api.ezidebit.com.au';
                break;
            default:
                $domain = ' https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au';
                break;
        }
        $this->pciURL = $domain.'/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl';
        $this->nonpciURL = $domain.'v3-5/nonpci';
        $this->pulicRestURL = $domain.'/V3-5/public-rest';
    }
}


class paymentMethods{
    private $HDEziDebit;
    public function __construct($HDEziDebit){
        $this->HDEziDebit = $HDEziDebit;
    }

    public function createSoapClient($url){
        $soapclient = new SoapClient($url);
        return $soapclient;
    }

    public function getSoapClientResponse($soapclient){
        $response = $soapclient->__getLastResponse();
        return $response;
    }

    public function ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment($parameters){
        $soapclient = $this->createSoapClient($this->HDEziDebit->pciURL);
        $params = array(
          "digitalKey" => $this->HDEziDebit->DigitalKey, 
          "token" => $parameters['token'],        // The ads ID 
          "paymentAmountInCents" => $parameters['paymentAmountInCents'],
          "customerName" => $parameters['customerName'],
          "paymentReference" => $parameters['paymentReference'],
        );
        $soapclient->ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment($params);
        return $this->getSoapClientResponse($soapclient);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you need to extends php soap client in class like class paymentMethods extends \SoapClient.

Comment: I have tried that options but got same error Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl : complex type 'handleType', attribute 'base': The QName value 'layoutType' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition. in /var/www/html/Magento2.1.6/magento2/app/code/Ktpl/Designer/Helper/ShoapLogin.php on line 37

Comment: Did you find how to fix the "layoutType" bug ? I have the exact same pb...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `SoapClient` in magento2 like,

```
$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, ['trace' => $trace]);
```

Where is `$wsdl` is your URL and second argument is option you can set second option as null If you do not have any requirement. You can also check same in Magento class in below location

`app\code\Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier.php`

in `_createSoapClient` function

Answer (score 0):

You can create new file like SoapClient.php

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Api;

class SoapClient extends \SoapClient
{ 
  public function __construct(
    $wsdl
) { 
    // Your logic
}
```

}

After you can call in any file( if you want to pass some custom data to your API). Other wise call direct as per above keyur's  answer.

$client = new \Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Api\SoapClient($wsdl);